# What does the phrase 'no doubt a lot' mean?

Tags: multiple-negation

> 'no doubt a lot'

I never understand this phrase. Does it mean that people don't doubt? or that people doubt it much.

Comment: You say "***no doubt***" when you want to   emphasize that something is  certain or very likely: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/no-doubt -

Comment: The "a lot" probably refers to something that follows, as in: A luxury house in a desirable suburb would cost, no doubt, a lot of money.

Comment: Could you cite a complete sentence example?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the sentence in a fuller context:

Question: How much does that yacht cost?
Answer: No doubt a lot.

That means "undoubtedly a lot", or "certainly a lot", which in turn means "certainly very much".

Comment: Please note: in speaking one might say this. But often it's expressed as; A lot, no doubt. However, it is a spoken form, not a written form.